# ¿Existe alguna biblioteca o clase para crear una tarea programada en Vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, cron, schedule

Buen día comunidad.

Tengo pocos dias de programar en VB. En esta ocación me encuentro con una funcionalidad a desarrollar, la cual es relizar una tarea programada.

He estado investigando y veo que se pueden realizar implementaciones o incluso utilizar recursos del sistema para este fin, el pero es que desconozco si estas emplentaciones funcionaran en windows server, ya que algunas solo indican que son para windows 7 o el dinosaurio de XP.

Por eso pido ayuda al foro expertos en VB.net y saber si existe alguna biblioteca (soy Javero) que me pueda auxiliar en este paso, ya que quisiera optimizar lo mas posible esta parte en lugar de hacer mi propio Job.

Saludos y buen dia.

Comment: no termino de entender tu pregunta. las tareas programadas son del sistema operativo, no del lenguaje. queres que se autoregistre como tarea programada?

Comment: @gbianchi. En java son job y tambien se pueden definir como tareas programadas, con java las podemos crear a traves de Quartz, Schedulers de Spring, Timers, los cuales ejecutaran una parte de codigo a traves de un patron como el siguiente: "0 15 9-17 * * MON-FRI" --> de lunes a viernes pasados 15 minutos entre las 9 y 5 de la tarde. Lo que yo busco para VB es algo o similar como Quartz o Shedulers en Java. Espero que me haya explicado mejor

Comment: desconozco la funcionalidad de esas librerias en Java. tal vez puedas detallar como querrias que funcione tu programa?

Comment: @gbianchi. Es exactamente como lo comente arriba, necesito ejecutar un codigo (consulta y actualizacion a BD) cada cierto tiempo en un horario de 9 a 19 hrs. que sea de lunes a viernes, la ejecución del codigo se debe hacer cada diez minutos. Mi problema en concreto no es como implemtarlo, si no saber si existe alguna clase ya hecha en VB que me permita ejecutar un patron como el que te comento. **0 10 9-19 * * MON-FRI**

Comment: yo desconozco, tal vez otro te pueda ayudar. yo siempre lo que programe lo hice a través de tareas programadas en windows. Puede que java lo necesite porque es independiente del SO.

Comment: Muchas gracias @gbianchi. La opción que comentas ya la tenía en cuenta, pero no me dan acceso el servidor para realizar esta funcionalidad, **políticas de la empresa**. Agradezco tu ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.net). Es un *port* de una biblioteca de Java. La he utilizado en producción en varios proyectos y hasta ahora me ha ido muy bien. La API es bastanta amigable también, mira un ejemplo que crea un nuevo trabajo para ejecutar cada día a las 18 horas:

```
    IJobDetail sincronizarJobDetail = JobBuilder
                .Create<SincronizarClasificadoresJob>()
                .WithIdentity(SincronizarKey).Build();
    ITrigger triggerSincronizar = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule(
                s =>
                    s.OnEveryDay()
                    .StartingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.HourAndMinuteOfDay(18, 0))
                ).Build();
```

Los trabajos solo necesitan implementar esta interfaz:

```
  public interface IJob
  {

    void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context);
  }
```

Comment: Gracias @yorodm, ya estaba leyendo acerca de su implementacion

Comment: hay una libreria que funciona con cron, creo que esta disponible en nuget, pero sino en [github](https://github.com/bromanv/Quartz.TextToSchedule) con soporte para ingles, español e ingles